# Failed to load template: template/carousel/carousel.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I worked on angularjs and laravel here i use carousel slider and added below js

Angularjs :

```
app = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap','ui-bootstrap-tpls']);
```

Js:

```
ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js
```

Here is the my code:

```
<carousel interval="myIntervals">
    <slide ng-repeat="(key, recentinfo) in profilemyrecentgiving" active="slide.active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class='col-md-5 col-xs-5'>
            <div ng-if='recentinfo.contribution_story_id != 0'>
              <img class="cart-story-image" src='[[recentinfo.project_squ_image]]'>
              <img class="cart-storyproject-image" src='[[recentinfo.giving_story_image]]'>
            </div>
            <div ng-if='recentinfo.contribution_story_id == 0'>
              <img class="impact-history-image" src='[[recentinfo.project_rect_image]]'>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-7 col-xs-7 align-left'>
            [[recentinfo.project_title]]
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
```

It works fine in sometimes like when i refresh the page it will workd but when i came form another page at that time it angularjs gives error like

Error :

```
Failed to load template: template/carousel/carousel.html (HTTP status: {1} {2})
```

Any one have idea then please let me know..

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your Angular.js codes?

Comment: Hi @ jia jain : check it out i have updated my question with loaded angularjs no more code required in angularjs

Comment: Nope There is no angular code here. What is `profilemyrecentgiving` object having ?

Comment: @jia jain : Yeah it's a result set of array nothing else..